# Liquibase 2.0 slower than 1.9?

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

I've just upgraded to Liquibase 2.0.2 using the provided jar file, and I've found that it runs slower than its predecessor.  If no updates are necessary, it still takes about 15 seconds to run, compared to the <5 it took before.  I've updated the xsd formats as well.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has encountered this, as I'm afraid to see how long it will take when it has to do real updates to our production environment.  Thanks.

Here is a log with some simple updates:

```
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: ChangeSet foo ran successfully in 27ms
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: ChangeSet bar ran successfully in 11ms
[updateDatabase] INFO 9/20/11 11:41 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
```

Comment: Does your changelog have preconditions in the changeSets? Those can sometimes add time and some of that logic changed between 1.9 and 2.0